# Send file to output screen with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, file

I have a form: (shortened version)

```
<form class="form-inline" id="parts-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="import-parts">Import:</label>
        <input type="file" id="import-parts" />
    </div>
</form>
```

With the other inputs (just text/selects) - submitting works fine, but I have some jQuery to detect whether there's a file or if the inputs meet X amount:

```
if ($('#import-parts')[0].files[0]) {
    form.attr('action', parts_url+ 'output-screen.php');
    form.submit()
} else {
    if (i > 0) {
        form.attr('action', parts_url+ 'output-screen.php');
        form.submit()
    } else {
        alert('Error! You must have at least one part selected. Please try again.')
    }
}
```

The conditional is true (I know this because I get taken to output-screen.php) but doing:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_FILES);
        echo '</pre>';
    ?>
</div>
```

in output-screen.php returns empty arrays - what is wrong with my code? Why does it not show me what I'm expecting? Is the jQuery `.submit()` missing something I don't know about?

EDIT:

just to clarify further, it's a csv file (intent is to read the CSV and use data in it)

Comment: `<input type="file" id="import-parts" />` requires a `name` attribute?

Comment: @kerbholz .. ah HTML, my thorn on an otherwise perfect rose. My ignorance is not bliss xD will add in and let you know if it works xD

Comment: @kerbholz it worked :) PHP - no problem, comes to HTML attribute shizzle and everyone loses their mind xD

Comment: Grats, glad it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a silly issue - form input's need a `name` attribute.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes

amending input to:

```
<input type="file" name="input" id="import-parts" />
```

works, I can now use `$_FILES` and see my data. Thanks to @kerbholz for leading me in the right direction.